# Flyaway inducing oscillation - betaflight defaults

Tags: betaflight, pid-tuning

I'm tearing my hair out over this one - hopefully I've missed something simple. I can't tune this quad to be flyable without putting an extremely loose tune on it with agressive filtering. The build:

- AstroX225 frame
- Aikon F7 flight controller (F722, MPU6000)
- Tmotor Velox 45A ESC
- Emax ecoII 1900kv 2207
- Tattu R-Line 1000mAh 6S
- Frsky rx, radiomaster tx16s with ADC filter off
- eachine tx805 and a caddx camera

The blackbox logs look fine (other than all the oscillation), and I've even replaced the gyro on the board with a known good MPU6000 from an otherwise dead AIO board. FC is softmounted and I even removed the vtx from the top of the stack on the presumption it might be putting mechanical noise into the FC. RPM filtering is enabled and working, and BlHeli is doing variable PWM from 24-48kHz. This is an extremely powerful build, however I wouldn't expect this degree of flyaway oscillation just from having a lot of power, betaflight is better than that.

What other reasons are there for so much noise to be getting into the flight controller?

### edit

A different flight controller with an ICM20602 does not cause the same issues. It is an F4 (MatekF405STD) but is also running 8k8k with bidirectional dshot.

Comment: I have to assume you have calibrated the compass, accelerometer, GPS and radio. Is there an option to motor/ compass calibration? Large motors can cause issues with a compass.

Comment: No compass, ACC, baro, etc disabled. Just me and the gyro. I had considered electrical noise to be an issue but that would be a severe design issue on the FC side, as plenty of people run very noisy environments and I have plenty of decoupling